# Setting up a color bar in css

Tags: css

I am new to css and trying to draw in 3 separate parts of a single box. The box is defined like this in CSS:

```
 #nutrients .row .values li {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:29px;
    height:63px;
    border-right:1px solid #C9C3BA;
    list-style-type:none;
 }
```

I want to be able to do this:

```
<li><span class="min_graph" style="background:green" height="32%">
    <span class="normal_graph" style="background:red" height="22%">
</li>
```

where the min part would be the bottom third, the normal part would be the middle third, and the max part would be the top third.
I tried this in the CSS:

```
#nutrients .row .values li span .min_graph {
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
#nutrients .row .values li span .normal_graph {
}
#nutrients .row .values li span .max_graph {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

but clearly I'm not understanding how to focus on the 3 different sections of the box.
Thanks...

========

Thanks so much for all the help! I didn't explain this well enough.
I do want to use div. There are basically 3 sub boxes, the lower (min), the middle (normal), and the top (max).
I want "#nutrients .row .values li" to be the parent element.
Then, the min graph piece would be the bottom 21px; the normal graph would be the middle 21px; and the max graph piece would be the top 21px.

Then, within the bottom 21px (for example), I might want to fill 30% of it, or 50% of it, etc.

Cell 1: 
min graph piece - red, 21% of its full height of the bottom third
normal graph piece - white, and no text (the middle third)
max graph piece - white, and no text (the top third)

Cell 2:
min graph piece - green, 100% of its full height (the bottom third)
normal graph piece - green, and 46% of its full height (the middle third)
max graph piece - white

Cell 3: 
min graph piece - green, 100% of its full height (the bottom third)
normal graph piece - green, and 100% of its full height (the middle third)
max graph piece - green, and 46% of its full height

In other words, the percentages cannot go into the CSS definition file. The HTML has to be able to set the percentages.
But the CSS does need to allow me to write to the individual three pieces of the parent box.

I need to understand how to make "#nutrients .row .values li" into a parent div.

Comment: Any particular reason why you are trying to style two spans inside of one list item instead of just using 3 divs to achieve this?

Comment: @huzzah, thanks very much. No, there is no particular reason. I would just need to understand how to define the div's in the CSS.

Comment: Ok, so you using height of 63px is just for example then?  You say you want the HTML to determine the size but then you add percentages like 46%, 21%, etc.  You just need the PARENT container of each div to scale, correct, so no "fixed height" there?

Comment: Also, these 'cells'....is this each particular <li>?  I'm sorry, I'm confused, because for instance, in cell 3 you want the bottom third to be 100% of its full height, then the middle as well, and then 46% for the maximum height div.  Why don't you draw us a picture of what you want and post it here in your answer?

Comment: @huzzah, the 63px is fixed, of the parent cell. I want the "min part" to use up the lowest 21px; I want the "normal part" to be the middle 21px; and then the "max part" is the top 21px.

Comment: @huzzah, my wording wasn't good. Yes, the three individual subsections (cells) are all the same height. They are each 21px. But then I can control the percentage of how much I draw in each one.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22068/discussion-between-huzzah-and-sploiber)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gSvSy/) with your example.  Divs inside your `<li>` is the way to go, as a div is a block level element that works better for your needs.  You define a parent element, in this case, the `<li>` with the width and height that you want the whole thing to be.  Then it is just a matter of defining how big and what color you want each `<div>` to be.

```
<ul id="boxes">
   <li>
      <div id="top">Div 1</div>
      <div id="mid">Div 2</div>
      <div id="bottom">Div 3</div>

   </li>    
</ul>​

#boxes li {
position:relative;
float:left;
width:29px;
height:63px;
border-right:1px solid #C9C3BA;
list-style-type:none;
}

#top {height:auto}
#mid {background:red; height: 32%}
#bottom {background:green; height:22%;}
```

Comment: thanks so much for all this work that you have done! Please look at the original post - I edited it. I suspect that your solution is getting much closer to where I need to go.

Comment: You are welcome! You can always upvote my answer as helpful, that'll give me another few points boost, heh heh ;).

Comment: the solution did not quite work. I would like to chat or talk to you more, but only if you've got the time. We can do it here or chat is OK too.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you would want to use `<div>` elements to accomplish this, as `<span>` elements are not serving their intended purposes here. I'll go over accomplishing this both ways.

### **`<div>` Implementation:**

**CSS:**

```
/* To use %-based heights, the parent element must have a defined height */
.values       {   height: 500px; width: 100%;}

.min_graph    {   background:green;  height: 32%;}
.normal_graph {   background:red;    height: 22%;}
.max_graph    {   background:yellow; height: 22%;}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class='values'>
    <div class="min_graph">TEST</div>
    <div class="normal_graph">TEST</div>
    <div class="max_graph" >TEST</div>
</div>
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/FvKd6/3/)**

### **`<span>` Implementation**

Firstly - you will need to ensure that you are closing your `<span>` elements and you will need to use `display: block` to ensure that they are visible, as shown:

**CSS**

```
#nutrients .row. values li span 
{
    height: auto;
    width: 100%; 
    display: block;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<li>
    <span class="min_graph" style="background:green; height:32%">Test</span>
    <span class="normal_graph" style="background:red; height:22%">Test</span>
    <span class="max_graph" style="background:yellow; height:22%">Test</span>
</li>
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/FvKd6/)**

Comment: thanks so much. Please note the edits I made (a new second half of it). I suspect I need to understand a bit more how to change to div.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a css gradient to color the different sections:

I used this site: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

to produce this:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ff3232 0%, #ff3030 33%, #f9f227 33%, #f5f900 66%, #00ff00 66%, #00ff00 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ff3232), color-stop(33%,#ff3030), color-stop(33%,#f9f227), color-stop(66%,#f5f900), color-stop(66%,#00ff00), color-stop(100%,#00ff00)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ff3232 0%,#ff3030 33%,#f9f227 33%,#f5f900 66%,#00ff00 66%,#00ff00 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ff3232 0%,#ff3030 33%,#f9f227 33%,#f5f900 66%,#00ff00 66%,#00ff00 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ff3232 0%,#ff3030 33%,#f9f227 33%,#f5f900 66%,#00ff00 66%,#00ff00 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff3232 0%,#ff3030 33%,#f9f227 33%,#f5f900 66%,#00ff00 66%,#00ff00 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff3232', endColorstr='#00ff00',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Oh, but unless it's been changed, I don't think the iPad version of Safari accepts percentage gradients, only pixel count, so you may have to tweak that depending on your target user

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be able to achieve what you are looking for more easily with a color sequence or gradient (as mentioned by Robot Woods). I found a good reference to be https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient()#gradient_with_multi-position_color_stops

```
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to right,
     red 20%, orange 20% 40%, yellow 40% 60%, green 60% 80%, blue 80%);
}
```